# React Native button doesn't change the state

Tags: javascript, react-native

The state of my application doesn't change after I press the button specified in the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      displayText: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={(prevState) => this.setState({displayText: !prevState.displayText})}
        title="Display"
      />
      {this.state.displayText ? <Text>{this.state.text}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

If the function passed to onPress is modified so that it changes displayText to false, it works as expected (it hides the text). Most likely the problem is in this portion.

```
<Button
        onPress={(prevState) => this.setState({displayText: !prevState.displayText})}
        title="Display"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button
  onPress={(prevState) => this.setState({displayText: !prevState.displayText})} 
  title="Display"
/>
```

Is wrong, the prevState argument comes from setState as a function, but not from the onPress event :)

Should either be

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.setState({displayText: !this.state.displayText})} 
  title="Display"
/>
```

or

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.setState(prevState => {displayText: !prevState.displayText})} 
  title="Display"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Button
        onPress={() => this.setState({displayText: !this.state.displayText})}
        title="Display"
/>
```